# Unicode characters showing as codepoints from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, unicode

I have a website built in Laravel Blade where I'm getting information from a MySQL databse and placing it in a few places. It's in Spanish, so it has some accents, but in most places it shows things properly, except for a select I have. I've tried quite a few things, but nothing seems to be working.

The function that gets the data I need:

```
        $entities = Activity::select('entityAct')->distinct()->orderBy('entityAct')->get();
        $entidades = [];
        foreach ($entities as $entity) {
            $entidad = trim(rtrim(explode('":', $entity)[1], "}"), '"');
            $entidad = mb_convert_encoding($entidad, "UTF-8");
            $entidades[] = $entidad;
        }
        return array_unique($entidades);
    }
```

The select and the information there:

```
@php
    $entidades = \App\Http\Controllers\ActivityController::getEntities();
@endphp
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <select name="selectEntity" id="selectEntity">
        <option selected value="">Elige una entidad</option>
        @foreach ($entidades as $entidad)
            <option value="{{ $entidad }}">{{ $entidad }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

I checked the database encoding, it's utf8mb4. And the php website also has UTF-8 as its main encoding. What is going on?

Comment: If everything _is_ supposed to be "in" proper UTF-8 already - then why would you apply `mb_convert_encoding` to try and convert the value _into_ UTF-8 there?

Comment: It was a try to see if that fixed things and I forgot to remove it. I found out already the error seems to be when extracting the data from the database, though.

Comment: _". I found out already the error seems to be when extracting the data from the database, though."_ - found out how, exactly? Not sure how that would make sense though, if you are not doing anything significantly different there, than in all the other places ...? And what exactly does "showing as codepoints" mean to begin with?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but the data in the database can be seen with the accent, and when it's out and I try printing it to the website, one can see the accented letters turning into u\009e9 or similar. Again, only happens on the select for some reason, the same word in other parts of the website can be seen properly.

Comment: That sounds as if the data might accidentally get encoded as JSON, or something like that ...? `json_encode('ä')`, with all the other options left at their defaults, results in `"\u00e4"`.

Comment: That was the thing, forgot the data was returned as JSON. Thanks!

Comment: Is the column encoded utf8mb4?  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Show us an example of a codepoint.  Explain where the data is coming from.  Do `SELECT HEX(col)...` to see what is actually in the database table.